# Slice Texture2D to Mutilple Sprites, And use those as AnimatorClip

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[charater](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9bi3.png)
[texture png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXmPW.png)

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
Texture2D texture2D= new Texture2D(96,96);
texture2D.LoadImage(buffer);
texture2D.filterMode = FilterMode.Point;
int width = 96 / 4;
int height = 96 / 4;
sprites = new Sprite[16];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            Rect rect = new Rect(j*width,i*height,width,height);
            Sprite sprite = Sprite.Create(texture2D, rect, new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f),
                16f,1,SpriteMeshType.Tight,Vector4.zero);       
            sprites[i * 4 + j] = sprite;
                        
         }
}
```

I get a png(96*96), and slice it into 16 24*24 sprites by c# script. Then use them to form some AnimatorClips, such as leftwalk, rightwalk, leftIdle and so on. It works well but with a little defect(There are extra pixels on top of the player's head), I want to know why. Thanks~~

I want to know how this problem arose and to be solved.